# Call onSaveInstanceState without calling super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)

Tags: java, android

If I will use this code without calling super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

```
@Override protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putLong(ID, mId);
}
```

like this:

```
@Override protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {      
        outState.putLong(ID, mId);
    }
```

What problems can be?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The activity itself saves some of the values in the bundle e.g state of the Fragments, if you do not call the super method, those values will not be saved.